# Notification when values within collection change

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I'm working on a custom controller for a Windows 8 store app in C#.
I added some DependencyProperties; some simple ones (like `Radius` below) and a collection of custom items used to construct and draw various shapes (`NinjaSource`).

```
<StackPanel>
    <cc:NinjaControl Margin="120,0,0,0" NinjaSource="{Binding NinjaCollection}" Radius="45"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The collection looks like this

```
public ObservableCollection<Ninja> NinjaCollection{ get; set; }
```

And the Ninja class basically has some properties and implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
public class Ninja : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;
        private double _value;
        private Path _path;
        private bool _showName;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _name) return;
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        ...
```

Whenever a simple property, like `Radius`, is changed, my custom control picks it up and redraws like this:

```
public sealed partial class NinjaControl: UserControl
{
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Radius", typeof (double), typeof (NinjaControl),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(default(double), PropertyChangedCallback));

        ...

        private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var instance = o as NinjaControl;

            if (instance == null) return;
            instance.RedrawMyControl();
        }
```

This works great, I can bind Radius to whatever I want and the `PropertyChangedCallback` is called whenever it changes.

I want the same thing to occur whenever any values *inside* the NinjaCollection change.

I have a DependencyProperty registered for the actual collection, with a property wrapper, but I believe it will only look at changes to the actual collection and not the values within.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NinjaSourceProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register("NinjaSource", typeof(ObservableCollection<Ninja>), typeof(NinjaControl), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Ninja>(), PropertyChangedCallback));
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please post the xaml of your control (the part when you use NinjaSource), the problem is probably there

Comment: My control does not have any XAML, except from an empty canvas. The control is entirely constructed from code

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is instead of exposing ObservableCollection as NinjaSource. Create a custom object that contains the observable collection. Expose specific Add Remove methods which will allow you to then raise events.

Comment: The problem I have is not with adding and removing items in the collection, rather updating properties within the objects of the collection. The ObservableCollection is part of a custom obejct, which I am using as data source of the page that is using the control.

Comment: Do you want to raise collection modified if item is updated? You just have to raise corresponding proprtychanged event